# faulty weight rice

Tags: linear-algebra

A shopkeeper has a faulty balance, in which the two pans have unequal weights. With this balance, he weighs $10$ kg of rice. However, the customer insists that the rice be kept in the other pan and weighed. The weight of the rice then turns out to be $8$  kg. Find the actual weight of the rice.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take $w$ as the extra weight on the right side of the balance and $t$ kg is weighed.

Given that $10$ kg of the rice is weighed which means that $w+t=10.....(1)$

$t=w+8.....(2)$

Now solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ and find $t$ and $w$, then you will get your answer.

Comment: can you pls explain t=w+8? what is the underlying concept?

Comment: @sam That is the equation I took for the rice which is on left side of balance and 8 on the other end

Comment: Thanks i got it.